# 238.Product of Array Except Self-Leetcode

Tags: java, arrays, prefix-sum

I have been trying out this problem on leetcode. ***[238.Product of array except self](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/)***

> Given an integer array **nums**, return an array answer such that
> **answer[i]** is equal to the product of all the elements of **nums** except
> **nums[i]**.
>
> The product of any prefix or suffix of nums is guaranteed to fit in a
> 32-bit integer.
>
> You must write an algorithm that runs in **O(n)** time and without using
> the division operation.

> **Example 1 :**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
>
> Output: [24,12,8,6]
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [-1,1,0,-3,3]
>  
>  Output: [0,0,9,0,0]
> ```

This was my solution to the above-given problem.

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
   
    int answer[]=new int[nums.length];
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        int prod=1;
        for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++){
            if(j!=i)
                
                prod=prod*nums[j];
        }
        answer[i]=prod;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This is passing 19/20 test cases. There is one test case that is not working and I'm getting an error ***"Time limit exceeded."***

Test case which is failing is given below:

> ```
> Input: [-1,-1,-1,-1,..............];
>  
> Output: Time limit exceeded.
> ```

If someone can help me with what edition I have to do to my code?

Answer (score 9):

i too do leetcode, it's giving you TLE, because it's not the solution they are expecting. it's correct but it will O(N*N) operations to compute, there is much better solution with O(N),

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
          
        int output[] = new int[ nums.length];
        
        output[0] = 1;

        // left prefix product
        for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
             output[i] = output[i-1] * nums[i-1];
        }
        
        int product = 1;

        for(int i=nums.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            
            output[i] = output[i] * product;
            
            product*= nums[i];
        }
        
        return output;
}
```

Comment: This solution ought to be presented with the explanation that the product of the array excluding any index is equal to the product of the product of the sub-array to the left of that index and the product of the sub-array to the right of that index.  This was not initially obvious to me, at least.

Comment: Not related, but it's surprising how this Java easily looks like Dart code, besides the list declarations.

Answer (score 2):

This solution also gives O(N) but use only 1 cycle.

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int[] res = new int[nums.length];
    res[0] = 1;
    res[nums.length-1] = 1;
    int n = 1;
    int k = nums.length-2;
    int fromLeft = 1;
    int fromRight = 1;
    while(n < nums.length) {
        fromLeft  = nums[n-1] * fromLeft;
        fromRight = nums[k+1] * fromRight;
        if (n < k) {
            res[n] = fromLeft;
            res[k] = fromRight;
        } else {
            if (n == k) {
                res[n] = fromLeft * fromRight;
            } else {
                res[n] = fromLeft  * res[n];
                res[k] = fromRight * res[k];
            }
        }
        n++;
        k--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: sharp cut solution

Comment: I like that this only uses 3n + O(1) multiplications, and half of them can be done in parallel because the pairs are write/read independent.

Answer (score 1):

The above problem is giving TLE (Time Limit Exceeds) because the above problem is solved in O(N^2) time complexity. As mentioned in the Question, Algorithm should run in O(N) time and without using the division operator.

**Approach-1**

```
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {

    int[] leftProduct = new int[nums.length];
    int[] rightProduct = new int[nums.length];
    /**
      calculate the left Prefix and right Suffix Product.
    */
    for (int i=0,j= nums.length-1; i < nums.length; i++, j--) {
        if (i == 0) {
            leftProduct[i] = nums[i];
            rightProduct[j] = nums[j];
        }else {
            leftProduct[i] = leftProduct[i-1] * nums[i];
            rightProduct[j] = rightProduct[j+1] * nums[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            nums[i] = rightProduct[1];
        }else if (i == (nums.length - 1)) {
            nums[i] = leftProduct[i-1];
        }else {
            nums[i] = leftProduct[i-1] * rightProduct[i+1];
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(N)**,
**Space Complexity: O(N)**

This can also be solved in O(1) space (as it's mentioned Output array does not count as  extra space.)

Hint: ***use the output array to store the left Prefix Product & traverse the array from the right side***.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] arr) {
       int[]  res = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i =0, temp =1; i < arr.length;i++){ // first iteration to make res making temp inc
            res[i] = temp;
            temp *= arr[i];
           }
        for(int i = arr.length -1 , temp =1;i>=0;i--){
            res[i] *= temp;
            temp *= arr[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
}

**Time Complexity O(N) Space Complexity O(N)**
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and your first one! The code however seems logically equivalent to the answer provided earlier by @Vishen. On StackOverflow such duplicate answers are typically not include. Perhaps it is better to delete this answer, and instead look for a question on StackOverflow for which there is no answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
def productExceptSelf(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    l=[]
    if nums.count(0)>=2:
        return [0]*len(nums)
    if nums.count(0)==1:
        index_of_zero=nums.index(0)
        k=nums
        s=1
        k.remove(0)
        for i in range(len(k)):
            s=s*k[i]
        l=[0]*len(k)
        l.insert(index_of_zero,s)
        return l
    else:
        s=1
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            s=s*nums[i]
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            l.append(s//nums[i])
        return l
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this question recently.

This is how I solved it (definitely after the interview :p ) in **Java8**.

```
private static List<Integer> getProduct(final int[] inputs) {
    int length = inputs.length;

    int[] prefixArr = new int[length];
    int[] suffixArr = new int[length];

    //leftArr
    prefixArr[0] = 1;
    //rightArr
    suffixArr[length - 1] = 1;

    for (int index = 1; index < length; index++)
        prefixArr[index] = inputs[index - 1] * prefixArr[index - 1];

    for (int index = (length - 2); index >= 0; index--)
        suffixArr[index] = inputs[index + 1] * suffixArr[index + 1];

    return IntStream
             .range(0, length)
             .mapToObj(index -> prefixArr[index] * suffixArr[index])
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ;
}
```

This solves the problem in 2 loops ideally and one stream iteration, hence **O(n)** is satisfied.